# Change magento2 price priority (Original price , Special price , Tier Prices , Group prices)

Tags: php, magento2

We know that magento2 has multiple prices type , for example special price, tier prices, group prices , if one prodcut has multiple price , the magento2 will show the minimum price .

```
Scenario 1:
Regular Price = 250
Special Price = 200
Group Price (NOT LOGGED) = 180
*** Result in product page: 180

Scenario 2:
Regular Price = 250
Special Price = 120
Group Price (NOT LOGGED) = 180
*** Result in product page: 120
```

So my question is how to ignore the minimum price , i want to set the group price highest priority , like below sample , i want to show price is 180

```
Regular Price = 250
Special Price = 120
Group Price (NOT LOGGED) = 180
```